# Different PFInstallation versions

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I have an application running on both iOS and Android platforms. They are the same version, but Parse logs two different types of version in PFInstallation objects.

As you can see in the screenshot below, on Android is logged the short version code, while on iOS is logged the build version code. Why?

[image]